# Terminal blank when opening

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes, window

Hello Ubuntucommunity!

So I just recently formatted my Laptop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and started playing around with it a bit. Since it's my second PC that I can use, I thought I could got all crazy with it, so I did. This is why I have now the Gnome Shell, along with some Ubuntu-Tweaks and Gnome-Tweaks to make it look like some sort of OSX.

Now I built the new Atom.io yesterday and after I had done so, I thought that the background of my Terminal was not fitting, so I changed the color of the background and the font to black on white.

Anyhow now, each time when I open a new Terminal window, i see no commands or something like the usual;

user@computer:~$

If I press Strg+C it appears and I can type commands just as usual.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank all of you guys in advance!

Comment: You should ask your second question in a new question, but a bit of Google's help would be enough I think. Was the terminal working before changing the colors?

Comment: Ok, will do! The Terminal did work before I changed the color.

Comment: Does this happen with any other terminal emulators? Try `xterm` or `rxvt`. If so, please [edit] your question and post the contents of your `~/.bashrc`. It sounds like you're launching a command from it  which does not exit.

Comment: Sorry I went offline yesterday evening, didn't expect such quick answers. I tried with rxvt and I get the same issue.

Comment: I also opened up .bashrc and saw the thing which was blocking me. I probably got a step in the Atom.io building process wrong and put some lines in this. Anyway I removed the last two lines which I put in and now it works again. Thank you a lot!